# "lvalue required as left operand of assignment" when using pointers in C

Tags: c, pointers

I want to practice with pointers in C. I got an error showing "lvalue required as left operand of assignment". The error shows at &y=&x. So how could I over wright the address of x to y?

```
int main()
{
    int x=3;
    int y=4;
    &y=&x;
    printf("x=%p,y=%p",&x,&y);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `&y` is simply the ***address of*** the variable `y` -- you can't change a memory address itself -- you can only change what is stored at that address.

Answer (score 1):

y is a variable, &y is not so can't be changed. &y is just a way to get the address of that variable.

Answer (score 0):

The address of a variable is immutable.  They are not allowed to be changed.

What you can do is store that address in a pointer variable, and later change that pointer to point to something else:

```
int x=3, y=4;
int *p;

p = &x;
*p = 2;
printf("p=%p, &x=%p\n", (void *)p, (void *)&x);  // prints same value both times
printf("x=%d\n", x);   // prints 2

p = &y;
*p = 7;
printf("p=%p, &y=%p\n", (void *)p, (void *)&y);  // prints same value both times
printf("y=%d\n", y);   // prints 7
```